# can we execute sql query in serverless pool from pipeline azure synapse?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-synapse, azure-pipelines-tasks

Can we execute SQL query in the serverless pool from the pipeline in Azure Synapse?

We are trying to run the SQL query in the Synapse pipeline, we are not able to find a way to execute the same from the pipeline using the serverless pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Set up an Azure SQL Database linked service to SQL Serverless (Instead of the Azure Synapse Analytics one, which is used for dedicated sql pool).
Check this out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NlYNcAduQxE&t

Comment: This of course works, but Synapse does not have a built-in way to call a script which was developed as an sqlscript in the workspace. The only way to do this currently is to call the synapse workspace rest api to fetch the script and execute it.